# Parsing strange xml feeds

Tags: python, xml

May not be strange, but I have never used xml, or PHP, which is two of the things I am using for an upcoming project.

Anyway, I am parsing [this](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/feeds/verticals/good-news/index.xml) XML feed. Each `<item>` contains an `<enclosure url=...>`

Where `...` = URLs & image types etc

In Python 3 using `feedparser` I can use

```
feed = feedparser.parse("http://www.huffingtonpost.com/feeds/verticals/good-news/index.xml")
l = feed.entries[12]['title']`
```

just fine, but when I try to get the URL of an image using

`p = feed.entries[12]['enclosure']`

I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in <module>
    p = feed.entries[12]['enclosure']
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\feedparser-5.1.3-py3.4.egg\feedparser.py", line 375, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
KeyError: 'enclosure'
```

So obviously `enclosure` isn't coming back with anything, I suspect this is because in the XML it does not use

```
<name of object>Text</name of object>
```

Instead it uses

```
<enclosure url=... blah blah blah />
```

How do I get the value of URL? It is equal to a string (`url="url is here"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [feedparse docs](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/reference-entry-enclosures.html) try using the *entries[i].enclosures[j].href* reference which returns the URL of the linked file:

```
feed = feedparser.parse("http://www.huffingtonpost.com/feeds/verticals/good-news/index.xml")

l = feed.entries[12].enclosures[1].href
```